# fetching thousands of urls with Newspaper3k and Multiprocessing slows down after few hundred calls

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, newspaper3k

I have a code which is meant to:

a) call an API to get Google SERP results;
b) open each retrieved url with the newspaper3k python3 library, which extracts the text of the news article;
c) save the text of the article into a .txt file.

The implementation of the multiprocessing part is as follows:

```
def createFile(newspaper_article):
    """ function that opens each article, parses it, and saves it to file on disk"""

def main():
    p = ThreadPool(10)
    p.map(partial(createFile), sourcesList)
    p.close()
    p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    main()
```

I have also tried with Pool instead of ThreadPool.

The problem is that after fetching and saving a few hundreds articles, it slows down dramatically.
Sometimes it may happen that a link takes some time to load but i'd expect the other routines to keep goin in the meantime.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: newspaper3k has a configurable ThreadPool.  Have you tried to use that ThreadPool?

Comment: No. That is supposed to be used with specific sets of sources (ex: nytimes, wapost, etc), not with the generic garbage that you can find on Google.

Comment: That is true.  You need to show more of your code, because the ThreadPool part might not be your problem.

Comment: Did you solve this question?  If not, please share the code in this function `createFile`.